# Trying to understand Peltier module specification

Tags: peltier, specifications

I baught [this](http://www.ebay.in/itm/TEC1-12706-Thermoelectric-Cooler-Peltier-12V-92-4Watts-with-MASSCOOL-Stars-700-/261570959738) module

The specifcation says:

```
 Product Specifications:

    * Operational Voltage : 12 VDC
    * Current Max : 6 Amp
    * Voltage Max : 15.4 VDC
    * Power Max : 92.4 Watts
    * Dimension : 40 x 40 x 3.6mm
    * Power Cable Length : 280mm
```

I am trying to understand each of these values, and have written what I understood:

**Operational Voltage : 12 VDC**
 This is the input power supply that should normally be used

**Current Max : 6 Amp**
This is the maximum current this device will draw from the power supply source. So it means my Power supply ratings should be 12 v Dc , 6 A (or greater than 6 A for safetly)

But under Recommendations it says:

RECOMMENDATION:

```
     * Use standard Power Supply 12V, 5A to power the TEC1-12706.
```

Is this 5A rating safe?

**Voltage Max : 15.4 VDC**
This is the maximum voltage that this module can handle.

**Power Max : 92.4 Watts**
This is maximum power or energy dissipated per second by this module. This energy will be used in cooling oneside of the module.

Kindly let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the module, and/or a better link. The link you provide doesn't work.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet I updated the link.

Answer (score 3):

This is a somewhat poorly written spec, but I think it's trying to say that you should aim to operate the Peltier at 12 V, at which point it will draw 5 A.  The maximum specs are what you should never exceed or the device could be damaged.

It seems these specs are meant for running from a 12 V lead acid battery, with some operating margin above reasonable charging voltage.  It's not clear whether 12 V or 15.4 V is the maximum cooling point.  However, it is clear you should design the power supply for 12 V nominal operation, it's OK if it occasionally goes a bit higher, but never over 15.4 V.

Comment: Usually the internal resistances varies by +-10% of these things (at some 25°C) and even more when operating. While running them at Imax should generally give some cooling effect, they are often specified to best operate at 0.7-0.8 Imax. Since cooling effect is roughly linear with current, this means they are best current controlled, which means that when running fully in heat the internal resistance can go to a point where you would need to apply more than Vmax to achieve Imax, which is usually the reason to specify some Vmax at all.

Comment: Considering that `15.4 * 6 = 92.4`, this spec doesn't look like something the manufacturer measured, or put any considerable effort into.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is the current that needs to be limited by altering the voltage. The overall power is determined by voltage multiplied by current. From the spec it looks like you can run this from 12VDC without a problem. However, when first connecting it up check the current with a multimeter to make sure current is within limits.

Comment: Can you tell me what is Current Max : 6 Amp?

Comment: When the term "maximum current" is used it does not mean you should use it at this current, just that it will probably survive it. Same with "maximum voltage". My advice is to keep the current to 5A

Comment: Breure Do I have any control on the current? (I though it depends upon the impedence of the module)  What should I do to keep the current to 5 A ?

Comment: If you use a 12VDC supply the current should be around 5A without regulation, but you need to check

Comment: Dirk Bruere I understand this current will depend upon how much is the load offered by the module. I = V/R, here R is the  resistance offered by the module. So if R is 1 ohm, then current could be 12 A.

Comment: In general, yes. However, I suspect that the resistance of the peltier changes as it begins to work. Not really sure though. Like I said, connect your module through a multimeter set for current to a 12VDC PSU and make sure the current if within limits. Experiment generally beats theory.

Answer (score 2):

Peltier effect modules really ought to be powered by a constant current source. If you try to power them from a constant voltage, the current will increase when the temperature increases. The increased current results in the diode heating up... so the current increases even more. Depending on the characteristics of the supply and the diode, this vicious cycle can continue until the diode burns out. The same is true for LEDs.  That's why you will nearly always see low power LEDs in series with a resistor.  The resistor (approximately) converts the voltage source into a current source. The resistor swamps the diode's impedance change. A series resistor works fine for a diode that draws only a few mA, and it's really inefficient for higher power devices, like Peltier effect devices or power LEDs.

People seem to think power sources are always constant voltage (perhaps because they got used to working with batteries).  You can buy pre-made constant current modules (try Amazon or eBay).  It's not too hard to build your own constant current source. For example, look in "Current Sources and Voltage References: A Design Reference for Electronics Engineers" by Lindon T. Harrison. Maybe your library has it. Better yet, get yourself a copy of "The Art of Electronics" by Horowitz and Hill.